# Automatic translation does not work in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-5

After changing the locale name and then print `{{ Config::get('languages')[App::getLocale()] }}`, it's giving me the locale name i.e. Italiano or Français. But it does not translate the website text into changed locale!

I am using following article for the localization [Laravel 5.2 localization](http://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale) also tried [Laravel Localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)but same also there.

From my understanding, it should translate the language automatically!

Need some expert help from the community.

Sample code from my view file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

 @section('content')
   <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          {{ Config::get('languages')[App::getLocale()] }}
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach (Config::get('languages') as $lang => $language)
                @if ($lang != App::getLocale())
                    <li>
                      <a href="{{ route('lang.switch', $lang) }}">{{$language}}</a>
                    </li>
                 @endif
             @endforeach
         </ul>
    </li>

    <h2>Welcome to my website</h2>
    <p>Please find your desired content by using website search function.</p>

@endsection
```

Comment: Did you have try to use `trans()` function?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization

Comment: Show your code from your blade files

Comment: @mcklayin I did not use trans() function. I just followed steps from the article.

Comment: @MikeMiller  Added source code from blade file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the text elements to translate? You need to use the trans() function and put your copy text in translation files.

EG

```
<h2>{{trans('welcome_message')}} </h2>
```

Then stick the copy in your language file

Comment: Thanks. I want to translate whole website after switching the locale by using dropdown list.

Comment: OK so what is stopping you? Post the value on drop down change, update locale and reload the page

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **languages** from nowhere, so if you want it to work, copy/paste following array in your **app.php**

```
'locales' => [
    'en' => 'English',
    'ka' => 'Georgian',
    'ru' => 'Russian',
],
```

And if you call `Config::get('app.locales')` you will get this locales.

Here is how your code must look like:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          {{ Config::get('app.locales')[App::getLocale()] }}
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach (Config::get('app.locales') as $lang => $language)
                @if ($lang != App::getLocale())
                    <li>
                      <a href="{{ route('lang.switch', $lang) }}">{{$language}}</a>
                    </li>
                 @endif
             @endforeach
         </ul>
    </li>

    <h2>Welcome to my website</h2>
    <p>Please find your desired content by using website search function.</p>

@endsection
```

Comment: Thanks. When I apply your code then it gave me following error message- "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /Applications/mamp5/apache2/htdocs/funtravel/resources/views/index.blade.php)"

Comment: Yup, sorry. Change in **app.php** *locales* with this:

`'locales' => ['en' => 'English',  'ka' => 'Georgian',  'ru' => 'Russian',],`

Comment: This will give you ability to change website locale, but if you want to translate contents you need to make proper folder structure in your **langs** directory. For this locales you will need following directories: **/resources/lang/en**, **/resources/lang/ka**, **/resources/lang/ru**. Then use `trans()` method to get translated keys from current locale

Comment: Thanks. Now it's showing "Undefined index: (View: /Applications/mamp5/apache2/htdocs/funtravel/resources/views/index.blade.php)" on line  "{{ Config::get('app.locales')[App::getLocale()] }}"

Comment: Can you tell me what is your current locale? in top of your **routes.php** write `dd(app()->getLocale());`

Comment: array:3 [▼
  "en" => "English"
  "it" => "Italian"
  "ru" => "Russian"
]
Current locales.

Comment: I need current **locale**, which is set in to your app. Maybe you have set locale, that isn't in your `app.locales`. So please tell me the result of your `dd(app()->getLocale());`

Comment: When I put dd(app()->getLocale()); in routes.php then it display array:3 [▼
  "en" => "English"
  "it" => "Italian"
  "ru" => "Russian"
]

Comment: From the app.php, I have set 'locales' => ['en' => 'English', 'it' => 'Italian', 'ru' => 'Russian',],

Comment: I've created [gist](https://gist.github.com/zgabievi/c0f3efa153044f67e84c) for you. If you will follow it, there won't be any problem. I've checked it with currently installed Laravel 5.2 Project.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. I have created a new project with Laravel 5.2 and updated app.php, routes.php and welcome.blade.php. Now it is showing "Locale:
- English

    English
    Georgian
    Russian" 
If I click on Russian then it does not change the locale. Always showing English.

Comment: There really is a problem with setLocale. It's saving locale for current request only. I'll help you if I find something usefull. Sorry for now.

Comment: Thanks @zgabievi. You really tried to figure out the issue. Please share with me if you find any solution to this. Again Thanks :)

Comment: I found some useful article. Can try this? http://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale